# Cannot serialize an interface

Tags: c#, web-services

I read in some answers that I have to add `ISerializable` to my interface, but the interface is used in a class and gives another error:

> 'SoapClient' does not implement interface member 'ISerializable.GetObjectData'

I'm trying to consume a `Web Service` but this is making it very difficult.

I consumed one Web Service before but didn't have this problem.

This is the interface I'm having problems...

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.Z_WS_DELIVERY_DOC_GET_DETAIL")]
public interface Z_WS_DELIVERY_DOC_GET_DETAIL
{       
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults = true)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.Z_WS_DELIVERY_DOC_GET_DETAILResponse1> Z_WS_DELIVERY_DOC_GET_DETAILAsync(ServiceReference1.Z_WS_DELIVERY_DOC_GET_DETAILRequest request);
}
```

All classes I have, I added `[DataContract]`

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
 [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style")]
 [DataContract]
 public partial class Z_WS_DELIVERY_DOC_GET_DETAIL1
 {
   // ....
 }
```

But nothing is working...

Comment: Easy, just serialize the insterface with `: serialize`, then try to avoid the other problem with another interface

Comment: What serializer is it that you're trying to work with here? also: interfaces... are usually a bad choice for serialization; some serializers support it, but not in all scenarios; some serializers just say "nope" and want concrete types; honestly, my advice here is "don't do this"

Comment: But this Reference was created by Visual Studio when I connected the Web Service.